# JPA findAllById returns ID order. Can I get data without the ID order?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I use Spring JPA. I am using findAllById(List ids). It returns data by ID order. But, the ID is created by UUID. The ID doesn't have any order information. I want to query data by order of the ids of input argument. Is it possible by using JPA?

Currently, I am using this to query data by order of the input ids.

```
ids.stream().map(id -> repo.findById(id)).filter(id.isPresent()).map(id -> id.get()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to know whether JPA provides something like findAllByIdByInputArgument and so on.

Comment: What is your `InputArgument`?

Comment: No it doesn't as the result has no order and depends on what the database returns you. Also your workaround is slow and basically a 1+N select problem.